# Why is Reward::lamports signed?

Tags: rewards, sdk

The `Rewards` type of the Solana protocol is the only instance of `i64` for lamports.

```
pub enum RewardType {
    Fee,
    Rent,
    Staking,
    Voting,
}

pub struct Reward {
    pub pubkey: String,
    pub lamports: i64, // <<< why?
    pub post_balance: u64,
    pub reward_type: Option<RewardType>,
    pub commission: Option<u8>,
}
```

All other instances of lamports amounts in protocol structs use `u64`. Is there a technical reason for this?

Are block "rewards" ever negative?
If they are not now, is it likely they would be in a future protocol upgrade? (e.g. slashing?)

Comment: This question isn't very good imo. Probably only the Solana protocol authors would know the answer to this. Posted it anyways to serve as Q&A material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacks to encode whether rent `Reward` entries are from the payer (-) or recipient(+)